# Android: Could not read image from disk and use them in a Imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, filenotfoundexception, bitmapfactory

I downloaded an image to the following target:

```
    String Target = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"Test.png"
```

At my smartphone, the file is located in (AFAIK) /storage/emulated0/Test.png.
Now, I want to read this file and load them into a ImageView.
My code ("id is Test.png"):

```
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Log.d("tags", "Is mounted");
    }
    else {
        Log.d("tags", "Is not mounted");
        return;
    }       

    Log.d("tags", "Path: "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+id); 
    File imgFile = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+id);
    if(imgFile.exists()){
        Log.d("tags", "File found");
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    }else {
        Log.d("tags", "File not found");
    }
```

The location on my smartphone is exactly the same like in this code, but everytime, I get a FileNotFoundException. Why?

Edit: I found a solution. Between the getExternalStorageDirectory and my filename I need a separator like "/". Now it works.

Comment: you get this - Log.d("tags", "File not found");?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, caused by a FileNotFoundException.